Digital Persona 4500 SDK Android Studio
I have a digital persona 4500 for my android project. Apparently it does not work When I try to run and check for available readers.
it says this:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libdpuvc.so" not found                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1082)                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1003)                                                                                                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)                                                                                                       at com.digitalpersona.uareu.jni.Dpfpdd.(Dpfpdd.java:34)                                                                                                       at com.digitalpersona.uareu.dpfpdd.ReaderCollectionImpl.(ReaderCollectionImpl.java:24)                                                                                                    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)                                                                                                       at com.digitalpersona.uareu.UareUGlobal.GetReaderCollection(UareUGlobal.java:37)

I'm missing the libdpuvc.so
I looked for it in the SDK folder but apparently it does not come with it. I know you have to put it in the project but the native library is missing from SDK folder. Where can I get the libdpuvc file or maybe you can give it to me whoever has worked on digital persona 4500 on android studio, is that possible?
